# Need to access an HTML element's class inside component

Tags: angular

I am making a Snack-Bar:

[image]

[image]

I want Snack-Bar to show up for 3 seconds and then it should be vanished. For that I am trying to remove "show" class after 3 seconds.

And for that I am making use of setTimeOut() function and want to replace "show" class with "" after 3 seconds.

What I am not able to get, is to get hold of "show" class inside my component. I tried to use template reference variable but don't know how to move further.

Thanks.

Comment: Please add a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example so we can help you immediately.

Comment: You're missing the whole point of binding. You have [class.show]="showBar" in your template. This means thet the CSS class `show` is added to the div if `showBar` is truthy. To remove the class `show`, all you need to do is to set `showBar` to false. And the Dom will update automatically. `showBar` shouldn't be an input.

Comment: Hi JB Nizet. Thanks for your response. Yes that was the point. I was missing the binding thing. I just made `showBar` to false in `setTimeout()` function and it worked.